# Do I need to use IObservable to track changes to my collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, system.reactive

Read quite a bit about IObservable and I am wondering what the pattern will give me (if anything) in my scenario.

I have a WPF application with a data grid, the grid is bound to an IObservable collection of Product.

```
ProductList.DataContext = AppState.Current.Products
```

... where AppState.Current.Products returns `ObservableCollection<Product>`

My objectives are:

- Track a list of changed objects
- Inform the UI that an object has changed so that I can enable the
  save button

My product class looks something like this...

```
public class Product
{
    string _desc;

    public string Description 
    { 
        get { return _desc; }
        set { _desc = value; } 
    }
}
```

Now if I update a description column on a row on my grid the setter for `Description` *does* get called. So I could book in some code here to set a `Dirty` flag on my product which I could then use to query for a list of changed products that need to be persisted to the DB.

I think that I could use IObservable to meet my second objective of informing the user interface that a row has been changed? Or is there an easier method such as some property on the grid?

If I am to use IObservable I have seen examples where the product exposes events that can be subscribed to. However, I dont want to hook up event handlers to all of my objects. I need something that tells me in general when any object in the collection has changed.

Additionally, how would I hook up this notification to my UI.

Comment: Have you looked at INotifyPropertyChanged? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

Answer (score 3):

`ObservableCollection<Something>`, despite its name, has nothing to do with `IOberservable<Something>`. It implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and those are the interfaces WPF looks for in a binding scenario. So if you use data binding in your xaml while defining your interface, and bind to an `ObservableCommection<Something>`, the binding will be automatically informed when the collection changes, and the UI will be updated. You don't need to use IObservable there.

Don't get me wrong, IObservable is a very useful and very powerful pattern, if a little hard to understand. Personnally, I use it a lot. But this is not a case where you should use it.

Comment: Cheers - would you be able to provide an example of a binding that would work in my scenario?

Comment: There are a lot of examples in the Data Binding Overview at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#binding_to_collections

Comment: Hi, yes but what do I bind to and from? My grid, my collection? My button that I want to be enabled when the collection of products is dirty is just a toolbar button in my MainWindow.xaml.

Answer (score 0):

The interface [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) was implemented in the .Net framework for similar tasks, as per MSDN Library:

> The INotifyPropertyChanged interface is used to notify clients, typically binding clients, that a property value has changed.

Comment: I think this looks like the right approach. I think the datagrid can sort of automatically make use of this interface, but how do I make my UI detect when something has changed?

Comment: I'm not at my pc but heres a link from MSDN I bookmarked previously. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to two things.

> 1) Find out if there are any changes made in the your collection through DataGrid

Your setter is already getting called through the bindings so you can easily track that.

> 2) Tell UI that some changes have been made

I am not sure where that save button exists in the UI but where ever it is you can simply bind it's enabled property with a boolean property. As soon as you detect a change in your object, enable the button by setting the bool property value to true.

> I think that I could use IObservable to meet my second objective of informing the user interface that a row has been changed?

There is no need to use IObservable in this scenario. You are already binding to ObservableCollection that should be enough. You just need a simple binding to tell UI about enabling or disabling the Save button

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. Is there something on my collection I can bind to ?

Comment: i don't know where your button is

Comment: Its just on a toolbar on my MainWindow.xaml. This main window also contains the data grid.

Comment: then simply create a bool property and bind the button enabled property with it. No need to do add that inside collection. You would need INotifyPropertyChanged to notify something has changed

Comment: Hi where should I implement this bool property, lets call it "ProductsChanged". Would you be able to provide a simple example as I appear to be confused on where to put this property. Thanks again.